# Browser focus when multiple child browser are opened in selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Scenario: we have opened around 5 browsers using selenium namely b1,b2,b3,b4,b5. These all browsers have active sessions. While working on one of the browser like b4 which is hidden or off focused because of other browsers. How do we bring the b4 browser in focus or activate so that we run the autoIT script or scikuli scripts.

As b4 browser is behind other browser, this step which involves scikuli or autoIT fails.

Any recommendations or suggestions are welcomed.

We tried using below solutions:

```
option 1: new Actions(driver).moveToElement(element).click().perform();
option 2: JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("document.getElementById('elementid').focus();");
```

None of the above options worked. We tried using ROBOT class, nothing worked.

Comment: Are all of the 'browsers' in one selenium session? If so, they're actually windows within a selenium session. You have to switch to the window first, then search for the element. Not sure if I understand your situation enough.

Comment: No. There are different browser sessions opened in the same execution. Every browser holds a different application.

Answer (score 0):

Before running your sikuli script, you have to move the focus to the b4 browser window. After that you can run your Sikuli script.

```
var current_active_window = driver.getWindowHandle();
var child_windows = driver.getWindowHandles();

driver.switchTo().window(child_windows[3]);
```